# 2Darray column slicing using 2 square brackets

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, slice, numpy-slicing

Defining a 2D array:

```
array_2D = np.array([[20,30,40,50,60], [43,54,65,76,87], [11,22,33,44,55]])
array_2D
```

Output:

```
array([[20, 30, 40, 50, 60],
       [43, 54, 65, 76, 87],
       [11, 22, 33, 44, 55]])
```

Need to change the values of the last column
But I cannot do it using the code below

```
array_2D[:][-1] = 10
array_2D
```

Output:

```
array([[20, 30, 40, 50, 60],
       [43, 54, 65, 76, 87],
       [10, 10, 10, 10, 10]])
```

Here the value of the last row is being changed rather than the last column

Whereas it works if I were to do it using a comma

```
array_2D[:,-1] = 10
array2D
```

Output:

```
array([[20, 30, 40, 50, 10],
       [43, 54, 65, 76, 10],
       [11, 22, 33, 44, 10]])
```

Is row slicing not possible in an array???
Because column slicing works just fine

Answer (score 0):

I have hard time understanding what is you question.

But I take that you already know how to do this.

```py
# Change values of the last column
array_2D[:,-1]=10
# Change values of the last line
array_2D[-1,:]=10
```

So, if I understand correctly, your question is why you can't do that with

```py
array_2D[:][-1]=10
# and
array_2D[-1][:]=10
```

Second line works, because `array_2D[-1]` is the line line, so it is 1 1D array. And then `array_2D[-1][:]` is the same line.
Generally speaking `anArray[:]` is just the same thing as `anArray`, or said otherwise `[:]` is a useless indexing.

So `array_2D[:][-1]` is the same thing as `array_2D[-1]`. While `array_2D[-1][:]` is also the same thing as `array_2D[-1]`.

There is a reason why the comma notation exists. When you use list indexing, (`[...]` without commas), you are dealing with your array as just an iterable.

If, instead of arrays, you had list (for which, there is no commas), you could still select the last line (the last element of the list of list) by doing `list_2D[-1]` and do something with it. But there is no way to select the last column (that is the last element of a line, for each line of the list), without doing it explicitly, like

```py
[l[-1] for l in list_2D]
```

If you want to skip commas, and other ndarray specific things, you are stuck with

```py
for l in array_2D:
    array_2D[y][-1]=10
```

The whole point of comma, is precisely to avoid having to do that (and use the powerful batch operations of numpy, in other words, let that for loop be a C for loop inside the code of numpy)

Now, if your problem is just that your comma key is broken, and you are willing to use numpy possibilities, you could also

```py
array_2D.T[-1]=10
```